# How to redirect the page according to user when I login in ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four different modules in my website: customer, operator, engineer and admin.

When I click on the login button at that time if that is customer the page should be redirected to the customer.aspx.

Ff engineer login then the page should be redirected to the engineer.aspx and so on..

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using "plain" ASP.NET with WebForms. In this case (again I suppose) you have the login control on your page, like this:

```
<asp:login id="ctrlLogin" runat="server"></asp:login>
```

That control exposes few events you can use, one of them is fired after authentication. Set up your login control like this:

```
<asp:login id="ctrlLogin" runat="server" onloggedin="OnLoggedIn">
</asp:login>
```

Now your your C# code add the method `OnLoggedIn`:

```
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

There you can redirect to the right page using a simple call to `Response.Redirect()`. Last question is how to get the "job" of the user, if you're using ASP.NET authentication with roles you can set-up your users to belong to that roles (customer, operator, engineer, admin). Actually an user can have multiple roles so you may need to *search* for the roles you're interested in. A quick and dirty solution is to have a function like this:

```
private void RedirectToProperPage(params string[] roles)
{
    foreach (string role in roles)
    {
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(role))
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/{0}.aspx", role));
    }
}
```

In your `OnLoggedInMethod` you can simply do this:

```
protected void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RedirectToProperPage("Admin", "Operator", "Engineer", "Customer");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [`Login`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t863ehhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control then it has a [`LoggedIn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event you can use to perform custom logic after the user has logged in.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add one more column in your table, where you have stored username and password of users.
In new column you can save the role of the user. When user enter right username and password then you can fetch his role and redirect the users according to his role.

for example:

If you fetch **customer** then you can redirect user to customer.aspx

and same check for other roles.

Comment: The ASP.Net Sql Membership and Role tables already have this built in. You don't have to edit your tables at all.

Comment: What @Josh said... plus having one column for Roles is a bad idea.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I have just given a simple and easy way to do it. How is it bad idea? please elaborate..

Comment: @aManCodE It becomes difficult to manage when you introduce multiple Roles per User, which is inevitable.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev by the way he didn't ask for multiple roles per user.